# In PhantomJS, why does jQuery call cause script to hang?

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS 2.0.0, on a Mac OS X Yosemite:

```
$ phantomjs --version
2.0.0
```

My script, shown below, appears to hang at the line where `$('h1').size()` is called:

```
system = require('system');

function usage() {
  console.log("usage: phantomjs " + system.args[0] + " <url>");
  phantom.exit(1);
}

console.log("system.args.length=" + system.args.length);
if (system.args.length != 2) {
  console.log("usage bad....");
  usage();
} else {
  var url = system.args[1];
  var page = require('webpage').create();

  console.log("Opening page: " + url);
  page.open(url, function (status) {
      if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to access network");
      } else {
        console.log("Setting timeout...");
        window.setTimeout(function() {
          page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
            console.log("Searching for Seawolf Calendar...");
            console.log("h1.size=" + $('h1').size());

            console.log("Exiting with status 0...");
            phantom.exit(0);
          });
        }, 5000);
      }
  });
}
```

The script is invoked from the command-line like this, for example:

```
phantomjs download-framed-content.js "http://www.sonoma.edu/calendar/groups/clubs.html"
```

with output like this:

```
system.args.length=2
Opening page: http://www.sonoma.edu/calendar/groups/clubs.html
Setting timeout...
Searching for Seawolf Calendar...

[Hung ...]
```

Why is the jQuery call hanging the script?

Comment: I noticed you're never upvoting the answers that you get. I wonder why that is. Does my answer lack some information or is otherwise not good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS 2.0.0 doesn't show any errors for some reason (this is a known bug).

The error would be that `$` is not a function. If jQuery is present in the page, then you can use it in the page, but it won't work outside of the page context (inside `page.evaluate()`).

You can only access the DOM/page context through `page.evaluate()`:

```
console.log("h1.size=" + page.evaluate(function(){
    return $('h1').size();
}));
```

Note that you cannot use any outside variables inside of the `page.evaluate()`, because it is sandboxed. The [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) says:

> **Note:** The arguments and the return value to the `evaluate` function must be a simple primitive object. The rule of thumb: if it can be serialized via JSON, then it is fine.
>
> **Closures, functions, DOM nodes, etc. will *not* work!**

Comment: I just had trouble returning an array from page.evaluate().  Maybe that's a bug, too?

Comment: It's probably expected behavior considering the last part of my answer. If it is an actual array as in `[1, 2, 3]` then no this should not be a problem. Keep in mind that `$(selector)` is a jQuery collection that only mimics the behavior of a JavaScript array. It (and its contents) cannot be serialized in order to pass it outside.